# Extract KeyValue pair and convert it into JSON (Column and rows) using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, excel

I am working on Asp.net MVC. I want to import Excel data into one of my grids.  I read Excel file using `ExpandoObject` (dynamic)  and then converting it into key/value pairs. I would like to know how to extract KeyValue pair and generate a header and data row from that key/value pair in JSON format.

Data will look like this:

[image]

I want to convert this KeyValue into Header and row like:

```
[
    {"CustomerName" : "Messi", "City":"Buenos Aires", "Country" :"Argentina"},
    {"CustomerName" : "Ronaldo", "City":"Lisbon", "Country" :"Portugal"},
    {"CustomerName" : "Persie", "City":"Amsterdam", "Country" :"Netherlands"},
    {"CustomerName" : "Ronnie", "City":"London", "Country" :"England"}
]
```

I have used the following jQuery snippet but it doesn't work:

```
var arr = [];

$.each(dataReceivedFromServer, function (i, data) {
  var d = data.Key;
  arr.push({
         d: data.Value,
         });
  });
```

If I do above, it shows me `[{"d":"Messi"},{"d":"Buenos Aires"},{"d":"Argentina"}` and so on...

In short, I want to bind data from Excel file to `KendoUI` grid (all columns would be dynamic as user can select any file).

Does anyone know how to do this?

**Update # 1:**

@webkit - Please see below image as the output of Console.log

[image]

Comment: that highly depends on how data looks like

Comment: I can't fix column names as data is always dynamic. I don't have any control on it.

Comment: what does 'data' hold in your each loop? to debug this I would console --> for (var i in data) console.log(i," :: ", data[i]); --- and see what you get.. post it here if you can.

Comment: I have updated the question with the result of Console.log

Comment: @cr0ss - Thanks. But,  actually i want to create JSON. but in this jsfiddle, you're defining static JSON, which i don't want.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work, but have you tried `JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: @SoftSan Yes, I realized that later, sorry. The JSON from the fiddle is what you want to build?

Comment: @cr0ss - Yes, i want to build the JSON like that.

Comment: You're going to have to do some sort of processing because the data is not formed the way you want it.  You would need to loop through and build each JSON element from 3 separate elements (Customer Name, City, and Country).

Comment: @L_7337 - Yes i have tried JSON.stringify(data), but i didn't help me much.

Comment: @L_7337 - Yes, but it is not necessary that every time there will be 3 elements only. It depends on the selected excel file. User can select any excel file which can have any number of columns and rows.

Comment: Basically, each row is an object and you need to apply some standard so your programming logic will know when one row ends and another begins (no matter how many elements in the row).  I know this example is not a solution, but maybe it will help out.  I did this a while ago when trying to convert a `table` to JSON: http://jsfiddle.net/leisenstein/vy3ux/

Comment: @L_7337 -Thanks for your help. But, it didn't help me much as again the columns are fixed in that sample.

Comment: Can you expect the same key order for every customer?

Comment: Well that i can't surely expect because it always depends on what user has selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend to transform the data before you receive it, as it would be more reliable. However, if this is not possible and you can guarantee that there is some grouping rules on your data set, you could apply the following:

```
var customer = {
    //this transform asserts the key value collection will be in a groupable order
    transform: function(coll, groupBeginKey){
        var result = [];
        var currentObject = {};
        var size = coll.length;
        $.each(coll,function(idx,data){
            //check if we are beginning 
           var defined = (typeof(currentObject[data.Key]) !== 'undefined');

            if(!defined && 
               data.Key === groupBeginKey){
                currentObject = {};
            }else if((defined &&
               data.Key === groupBeginKey)){

                result.push(currentObject);
                currentObject = {};
            }
            //set the property on the object
            currentObject[data.Key] = data.Value;
            //handle last
            if(idx >= size-1){
                result.push(currentObject);
            }
        });

        return result;
    }
};
```

For the following data set (I have simplified it for simplicity):

```
var data = []

data.push({ "Key": "CustomerName", "Value": "Paul"});
data.push({ "Key": "City", "Value": "Las Vegas"});
data.push({ "Key": "CustomerName", "Value": "George"});
data.push({ "Key": "Zip", "Value": "1234567"});
data.push({ "Key": "City", "Value": "New York"});
data.push({ "Key": "CustomerName", "Value": "Joe"});
data.push({ "Key": "City", "Value": "Omaha"});
```

Asserting that the customer can be grouped from CustomerName to City, you use it as follows (it will include the customer that has a zipcode):

```
var results = customer.transform(data,"CustomerName");
```

Please see it in action at the following jsfiddle (look in the debug console for output):

http://jsfiddle.net/pHQze/